# error on adding webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

i just created a webservice with visual studio 2010 and .net 4, and published it to my website subdomain. [subdomain has virtual directory and i have set the rules].
when i try to add my webservice to other c# project from "add service refference" => "advanced" => "add web refference" it just show me this error in "webservice found section"

The document at the url http://service.proapp.ir/sedardIP.asmx was not recognized as a known document type.
The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:

### - Report from 'XML Schema' is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=utf-8').'.

i added .svc application/octet to mime but nothing has changed i added

```
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpSoap"/>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
    <add name="Documentation"/>
  </protocols>
</webServices>
```

too but nothing has changed , can u plz help me?????????????

**tried adding refference without advanced throwing this error :**

The document at the url service.proapp.ir/sedardIP.asmx was not recognized as a known document type.
The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:
- Report from 'XML Schema' is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=utf-8').'.
- Report from 'DISCO Document' is 'There was an error downloading 'service.proapp.ir/service/sedardIP.asmx?disco'.'.
  - The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
- Report from 'http://service.proapp.ir/sedardIP.asmx' is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=utf-8').'.
- Report from 'WSDL Document' is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=utf-8').'.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'service.proapp.ir/sedardIP.asmx'.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'service.proapp.ir/sedardIP.asmx'.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

Comment: Try with this URL, http://service.proapp.ir/sedardIP.asmx?WSDL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, adding your web service reference straight - instead of going in the advanced section -  from the service reference panel has never caused me any problem.
Perhaps try that.

Failing that, this will work:

try the same process `service reference > add service reference` with the following url

http://service.proapp.ir/sedardIP.asmx?WSDL

Comment: @user3475113 You didn't add any error to your comment.

Comment: i added it at the end of the main post , cause its too long for comment

Comment: dir Dura, i just got another problem, i successfully add the webservice but , its not working and throw exception, "more than one endpoint" so i deleted one of endpoints in app.config , and it throwes another exception that tells there is no endpoint listening to request and server throws 404 not found, do u know what is the problem?

Comment: i tried both of them , keeping first deleting second and keeping second one and deleting first one, but nothing has changed, i also checked it on my local iss (visual studio iis) and it workd by deleting second one

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question, explaining the new scenario, including your app.config code and perhaps linking to this question. I'll try to answer there.