# Errors calling web service, " more than one endpoint configuration for that contract" or "no endpoint listening"

Tags: c#, web-services

i just had a problem adding webservice that its solved in this thread
[error on adding webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25321905/error-on-adding-webservice)

now i just have a problem by calling its method

this is my app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="sedardIPSoap" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="sedardIPSoap12">
                <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
                <httpTransport />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://service.proapp.ir/service/sedardIP.asmx"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="sedardIPSoap"
            contract="sedardip_set.sedardIPSoap" name="sedardIPSoap" />
        <endpoint address="http://service.proapp.ir/service/sedardIP.asmx"
            binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="sedardIPSoap12"
            contract="sedardip_set.sedardIPSoap" name="sedardIPSoap12" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

so when i try calling my function like this

```
sedardip_set.sedardIPSoapClient nm = new sedardip_set.sedardIPSoapClient();
nm.set_ip("x1", "x2", "x3");
```

it throws this exception

```
An endpoint configuration section for contract 'sedardip_set.sedardIPSoap' 
could not be loaded because more than one endpoint configuration for that 
contract was found. Please indicate the preferred endpoint configuration 
section by name.
```

so i tried deleting one of the endpoints from app.config, after that it throws this exception

```
There was no endpoint listening at http://service.proapp.ir/service/sedardIP.asmx 
that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or 
SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

inner exception

```
{"The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."}
```

i just run service on my visual studio (locally) and by deleting second endpoint its just worked !
so can anyone plz help me to get this working on http://service.proapp.ir/service/sedardIP.asmx plz??

Comment: Why delete _all_ the endpoints? The error just complained about there being **more than one**.

Comment: i didnt delete all of them, i just delete the first one and try it, in second try i deleted second one and keep the first one, so it means i allways have one endpoint

Comment: So, if you remove the second endpoint, you can call the method, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason you need to use a web reference? A service reference is the updated, newer way of doing things, but if you need to use the web reference for some reason then that's fine too.

If you go the service reference route you can specifically name the endpoint you wish to use, for example:

```
sedardip_set.sedardIPSoapClient nm = new sedardip_set.sedardIPSoapClient("sedardIPSoap12");
nm.set_ip("x1", "x2", "x3");
```

It may have a new name after setting up the service reference but you would just substitute the new name in place of the sedardIPSoap12.

Comment: actually when u said checking endpoint, i just see that the address that visual studio makes in app.config is physical path combined with logical path so i correct the endpoint address and removed the second endpoint , now its working greaaaat :D thanks. i changed http://service.proapp.ir/service/sedardIP.asmx  to    http://service.proapp.ir/sedardIP.asmx

Comment: it needs 15 rep , i just have 12 :|

Comment: @Ryan: he clearly uses a service reference. A web reference wouldn't put `endpoint` elements into the config file.

Comment: @JohnSaunders well the title of his problem says "web reference" hence my confusion :P. Regardless the problem's fixed.

Comment: Actually, it says "web service", not "web reference"

Comment: I guess I can't read lol, I thought he must have meant web reference by web service, but really it's trivial. The issue has been resolved.

Comment: Thanks for this. Had to say thanks because VS for some reason created more than one endpoint, and I wasn't selecting the one to use, as originally this worked with just one endpoint. Saved me hours.